# Not able to type into java Console

Tags: java, console

My console will not let me type into it. I am not sure if this is a problem with my code or the program itself.

```
import java.util.*;

public class assignment_2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    removeDuplicate();
}

public static void removeDuplicate() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Enter ten numbers: ");

    for (int i = 0; i == 10; i++) {
        if (numberList.contains(input.nextInt())) {

        } else {
            numberList.add(input.nextInt());
        }
    }

    numberList.forEach(System.out::print);
}
}
```

Comment: I think by mistake you wrote i==10 rather than i<10 in for loop.

Comment: does the input.nextInt() not work as a scanner function?

Comment: plus you don't have to declare your scanner twice either do it in main and pass it to function or just remove it from main if you don't need it further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is never executed.

```
for (int i = 0; i == 10; i++) { // here i==10 is never true as i=0
                                // so it should be i<10 or i <=10
    if (numberList.contains(input.nextInt())) {

    } else {
        numberList.add(input.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you can't believe i missed something so little.